# The DATE change from MySQL to NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js

Hi I´m using MySQL with NodeJS (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)

In Node Js I´m using MomentJS ([MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/docs/))

I do an INSERT with a DATETIME, I get the date this way

```
incomes.registerdate = this.FechaRegistro.utc().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss') //2019-11-20 22:02:42
```

The Date is storage correctly, but when I select the row in NodeJs the date change

```
RowDataPacket {
  item: '501021',
  description: 'CLAMP, 2" MUFFLER',
  price: 13,
  quantity: 13,
  rack: 'B-55',
  status: '1',
  registerdate: 2019-11-21T04:02:42.000Z,
  trackingnumber: 'test'
}
```

Why? I want get the same time that I inserted.

NodeJs is runing in localhost and MySQL is in a Server(Azure)

UPDATE

I found the problem.

The package mysql (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql), force date types (TIMESTAMP, DATETIME, DATE) to be returned like Object type Date(), but when NodeJS use the string got from MySQL  is used as localtime, but is UTC time.

In the conection we have an option to force date types  to be returned as strings

```
var mysql = require('mysql'),
    conf = require('./db-conf'),
    dbOptions = {
        host : conf.mysql.host,
        port : conf.mysql.port,
        user : conf.mysql.user,
        password : conf.mysql.pass,
        database : conf.mysql.db,
        dateStrings:true
    },
    myConn = mysql.createPool(dbOptions);


module.exports = myConn;
```

When I put this option in true all work fine, but how can I forse NodeJS to use the time in UTC instead of local

Comment: Why not [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)? Also how are you doing the insert?

Comment: looks like a timezone issue

Comment: check to make sure you have no auto update transformation in MySQL

Comment: @drtechno auto update about what. Can you give me an example?, I don't know what settings I can change

Comment: like on update: current timestamp inside mysql

Answer (score 1):

Best practice:

Always store datetime as UTC in the database.

`incomes.registerdate = moment(this.FechaRegistro).toISOString()`

When you display it in your app, use the UTC value returned from database and parse it with momentJS.

`var display = moment('2019-11-21T04:02:42.000Z').format('YYYY-MM-DD H:ma')`.

It will parse accordingly to your app's timezone.. unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: Iget the next error when I use toISOString()    code: 'ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE',
  errno: 1292,
  sqlMessage:
   'Incorrect datetime value: \'2019-11-21T16:09:29.803Z\' for column \'registerdate\' at row 1',
  sqlState: '22007'

Comment: I'm store datatime as UTC in the database.